# how to get uploaded file name in different upload form without clicking choose file?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a CRM, on uploading a file in one upload form. Is it possible to get that file name inside choose file in another form without clicking the choose file option?

This is the code for selecting file in one form.

```
if ($_FILES['product_image']['name']!='') {
    $target = "file_upload_source/"; 
    $target1 =$target . @date(U)."_".( $_FILES['product_image']['name']);
    $product_image=@date(U)."_".( $_FILES['product_image']['name']);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'], $target1);

    $getlead_id1 = $_GET['leadid'];
    // $appa = explode("_",$getlead_id1);   
    $data = explode("_",$getlead_id1);
    $lead_id545=$data[0];
    $type464 = $data[1];

    $sl= "
        INSERT INTO dizypro_file_order 
        SET lead_id = '$lead_id545',
            description = '$description',
            name = '$product_image',
            type = '$type464', 
            upld_date = now(), 
            maker_date = now(),
            maker_id = '".$_SESSION['ADMIN_GAME_ID']."',
            divn_id = '".$_SESSION['SESS_Division']."',
            comp_id = '".$_SESSION['SESS_COMPANY']."',
            zone_id = '".$_SESSION['SESS_zone']."',
            brnh_id = '".$_SESSION['SESS_Branch']."'
    ";
    mysql_query($sl);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want set the contents of a filefield to a predefined filename when you send a form. Every major browser will not let you do that, on security grounds. An unscrupulous site could display a filefield where the user can't see it, select the name of any file on your computer, put trick the user into uploading that file.

Short summary: **Not possible!**